# Google Keyboard sync doesn't work anymore

Tags: sync, gboard

```
Synchronisation for devices with business apps is not available
```

I added an Google Classroom account and since then I even couldn't change the sync account.
This account is now removed, but I have no business apps installed..!?

Comment: Try to delete Google Play Services cache